# How can I make a current source with no transistors or amplifiers?

Tags: current, current-source

I want to understand how these work.

Batteries are voltage sources as are generators.

When I searched all I find is a lot of transistors and amplifiers.

I wonder if it can be done with neither of them to make it simpler.

Comment: generators are not necessarily voltage sources. For example, AC generators using a rotor with permanent magnet are (given a sufficient rotation speed) a quite good approximation for current sources. For example the classic "6V 3W" bicycle generator is actually more like a 500mA current source, and delivers 3W at 6V because the combined resistance of the front and back light is 12 ohms. Connecting another 6V 3W bulb in sereies with the lighting system already present will power that bulb as well, yielding 6W at 12V! You need to drive faster though for the lights to reach full brightness.

Answer (score 8):

#### in general

As others have pointed out, a voltage source and a resistor can be used. ***But***... with the following rule:

```
Start with a lot of voltage and throw almost all of it away!
```

If you know the voltage compliance range over which a certain worst case current regulation must exist, then:

$$\%I_{_\text{SRC}}=\%V_{_\text{COMPLIANCE}}\cdot\frac1{\frac{V_{_\text{SRC}}}{V_{_\text{COMPLIANCE}}}-1}$$

#### illustration making and clarifying the above point

Suppose you need \$I_{_\text{SRC}}=100\:\mu\text{A}\$ and regulation to no more than 1%, or \$\%I_{_\text{SRC}}=\frac{\Delta\,I_{_\text{SRC}}=1\:\mu\text{A}}{I_{_\text{SRC}}=100\:\mu\text{A}}=0.01\$.

Suppose the voltage compliance range is \$0\:\text{V}\dots 10\:\text{V}\$ so \$\%V_{_\text{COMPLIANCE}}=\frac{\Delta\, V_{_\text{COMPLIANCE}}=5\:\text{V}}{V_{_\text{COMPLIANCE}}=5\:\text{V}}=1.00\$.

Then this means that the required \$V_{_\text{SRC}}=5\:\text{V}\cdot\left(1+\frac1{\frac{0.01}{1.00}}\right)=505\:\text{V}\$!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8RNTl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you short out the load, then \$I=\frac{505\:\text{V}}{5\:\text{M}\Omega}=101\:\mu\text{A}\$. If the load requires \$10\:\text{V}\$ (the maximum given in the earlier specification above), then  \$I=\frac{505\:\text{V}-10\:\text{V}}{5\:\text{M}\Omega}=99\:\mu\text{A}\$.

Note that this meets the specification that I've written above.

#### summary

The above shows the theory and applies it to one extreme circumstance demanding only 1% variation in order to make a point.

So. Yes. You can have a current source without transistors and amplifiers and only using a voltage source and a resistor to get there.

***But***... there are caveats.

Comment: For safety, considerations, that circuit will deliver non-negligible currents through much higher output resistances, too, e.g. into fingers of someone who touches the leads. 0.1 mA isn't dangerous, and apparently you wouldn't even feel a tingle below 1 mA.  But it can charge up any capacitors to 505 V, and destroy them via arcing as the capacitor supplies bursts of higher current.  Perhaps a Zener diode to clamp the output voltage would be a good idea for some applications, connecting it as part of the on/off switch. (The OP didn't restrict us to linear components only.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Different circumstances would suggest different voltages, some of them quite safe. The example is not meant to be anything but an illustration of how to understand and then apply theory to specific circumstances. It was chosen because of its `shock value` in getting the point across, no pun intended.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a constant current source with nothing more than a battery and a resistor - if the shortcomings of such a simple constant current source are acceptable for your use.  [The Wikipedia article on current sources mentions it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source#Passive_current_source)

A simple constant current source is nothing more than a resistor in series with a battery:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVxDNq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That simple circuit will give you a (somewhat) constant current of 1 milliampere.  If you short circuit the outputs, you get 1mA.  If you put a resistor between the outputs, then you get a bit less than 1mA.

If you do this, then you get 0.9mA instead of 1mA:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsUK7v.png)</sup>

Regulated to within 10 percent of the design value over a range of 0 to 1000 ohms.  That's pretty crummy compared to a constant current source using a transistor or other amplifier, but it's pretty darned good for nothing more than a cheap battery and a cheap resistor.

To make it work better, you use a higher voltage and a higher resistor in place of R1.  90V and 90kΩ gives you a constant current source that will be within 10 percent of 1mA over the load range of 0 to 10000 ohms.

The higher the voltage and the higher the series resistor, the better the approximation to an ideal current source.  An ideal current source has a battery of infinite voltage and a series resistance of infinite ohms.

There are plenty of practical reasons not to build current sources that way, but for simple experiments a simple current source made of a battery and a resistor might be enough.

Comment: Bear in mind, the way this circuit effectively regulates the current is by wasting power in the resistor. The larger the voltage and resistance, the better the regulation, but also the more power burned in the resistor. This is obviously a concern because of the power consumption, but the heat produced by the resistor will also be a limiting factor. You can mitigate this in various ways.

Answer (score 4):

Think of it in terms of fluid pressure and flow rate.

It's easy to maintain fluid pressure with a valve that opens should the pressure exceed a certain value. Or you can use a pressure sensor that turns up the speed of a pump.

It's quite tricky to maintain flow rate because you need some mechanism that linearly shuts down a valve should the flow exceed a certain limit and, when that flow is less than the prescribed limit, it should open the valve more to main the flow rate. So, it needs to measure flow rate and adjust the valve to keep it constant.

Measuring fluid flow rate accurately is a lot harder than measuring fluid pressure.

It's the same in electronics.

> *I wonder if it can be done with neither of them to make it simpler*

If you can solve it for fluids you might get rich.

Of course, if you had a big enough voltage battery and a high valued resistor you can begin to make a constant current generator. Imagine the battery was 1000 volts and the resistor was 1000 Ω. Clearly into a short circuit, the current is 1 amps. However, into a ten Ω resistor it would be 0.991 amps. Not far off. This is why we sometimes think of a current source as an infinite voltage source in series with an infinite resistance. It also explains why we regard a current source as having infinite source impedance.

Answer (score 3):

An illuminated photovoltaic cell is a constant current source, essentially one electron per photon collected. Of course, it's limited in voltage (but a real battery is limited in current, too). As long as you stay more than 100 mV or so below the open circuit voltage, the current is close to constant.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that when you say current source you mean a circuit or device that supplies a constant current to a load, the simplest current source is probably a voltage source and a resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbBZcs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the resistor is much higher in value than the load and the voltage is high enough it will act like a constant current source within a certain tolerance.

Example: You have a load that varies between 1k\$\Omega\$ and 10k\$\Omega\$ and you want the current through it to be 1 mA across that range. From Ohm's Law, the voltage across the load would need to vary from 1 V to 10 V. You could take a resistance 10 times the maximum, 100k\$\Omega\$ and put it in series with the load, the voltage to get 1 mA with the maximum load would then need to be
$$
V = 1~mA\times 110k\Omega = 110 V
$$
With the minimum load of 1k\$\Omega\$ you would get
$$
I = \frac{110~V}{101k} = 1.089~mA
$$
for a roughly 9% error. Using a 1M\$\Omega\$ resistor and 1010 V would reduce the error to 0.9%. So while you can get some current regulation this way, it tends to require high resistances and high voltages. This is why you usually see it done with transistors and opamps, they are able to get much better regulation at low voltages.

Another type of current source is the [constant current diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-current_diode), these are an FET with their gate shorted to their source, giving you a two terminal device that will regulate at a current dependent on the FET's parameters.